# Line spacing in dialogflow INTENT

Tags: line, dialogflow-es, chatbot, spacing

i am having a real simple problem !  how do you create a line spacing when writing the response on INTENT ?  i left spaces in my response but in the chatbot window, it is not displaying with the same line break / spacing format

[image]

Comment: Can you specify how are you displaying chatbot message in frontend?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At the moment, there is no support for web demo, but yes to use the dialog on facebook, slack, etc. the spaces you are using are supported. This can also be found in the Dialogflow documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to see the line breaks in the Dialogflow console. But the platforms support it.

Comment: hi, thanks.  platform refers to the browser ? how do i do that since my chatbot is inserted via just a iframe ?  thank you

Comment: Is there any hack to add line breaks in the response of dialoflow web demo with Java backend and Angular front end?